# PHP-Mailer - check if mail was delivered

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I use the popular PHP-Mailer-Class for sending emails. Is there any possibility to check, if the email was delivered successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, it's a bit tricky this question.
There are a few methods.

1. If it's delivered and read then you can have a 'tracker' image. This is an image that is actually a php page.

So at the end of the email I would have a link to an 'image' on my server. With a tracker identifier in it. for example

```
<img src="example.com/trackerImage.php?email=someemail.com" />
```

So now using php and gd you can make this page and get the email address (or other variables) (that you have set) to record that the email has been opened or read.

Another method is setting up a bounceback email address (you'll have to google). This email address can be read by php to process bouncebacks and let you know if the email is not longer available. There are scripts that can help you on this.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can check if it has been recieved, you can only check that it was succesfully sent.